# Passing byte array back to C++ caller from C#

Tags: c#, c++, interop, marshalling, dllimport

I have C++ library. To call some method from this lib I need to assign callbacks, that will be called during that method execution. One of them:

```
int(*cb_func_card_reset)(unsigned char(*ptrATR)[32]);
```

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate int cb_func_card_reset([Out][MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst = 32)]out byte[] atr);
```

Once callback is fired, this method executes:

```
private int CardReset(out byte[] atr)
{
    var atrResult = _reader.ActivateICC(); // 3B 78 96 00 00 81 00 03 50 01 07 90
    atrResult = atrResult ?? new byte[] { };
    var result = new byte[32];
    Array.Copy(atrResult, 0, result, 0, atrResult.Length);
    atr = result; // 3B 78 96 00 00 81 00 03 50 01 07 90 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    return 0;
}
```

Logs from this lib in this case show received bytes: `5878E90500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000`

On each run if I assign atr same value, result in library logs is different.

I've tried using pointer, but results are also random:

```
private int CardReset(out IntPtr atr)
{
    var atrResult = _reader.ActivateICC();
    atrResult = atrResult ?? new byte[] { };
    var result = new byte[32];
    Array.Copy(atrResult, 0, result, 0, atrResult.Length);
    atr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(result.Length);
    Marshal.Copy(atrResult, 0, atr, atrResult.Length);
    return 0;
}
```

The only thought I have is wrong pointer to array being sent into libray, but I have no idea what goes wrong.

Comment: Hey, I can't answer your question directly, but I would like to mention that we had a similar use case with callbacks that need to be passed into a C++ library. We used SWIG (https://www.swig.org/) to generate the interface for C# without any prior knowledge. This way, you could avoid having to deal with the marshalling yourself. IIRC, we needed to use a director to be able to provide the callback. I recently learned that dotnet has a moving garbage collector and you might need the fixed keyword when interfacing with C++.

Comment: Learn how to write interops : [C++/CLI in 10 minutes](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes)

Comment: How do you use this callback?

Comment: @shingo, I set pointers to callback functions and return them to the library. Then I call some method, that calls callback during execution

Comment: @boo-hoo, I'll check SWIG, but I want to know, what the problem is with this code

Comment: @PepijnKramer, thanks. But why I shouldn't I use .NET?

Comment: @grunge_scum C++/CLI is sort of the ".NET version" of C++. It's very useful for creating a .NET wrapper around C++ code.

Comment: Do you have a minimal C++ example?

Comment: @grunge_scum you will be using .Net, C++/CLI is C++ for .Net, you can allocate managed memory (and copy data from normal C++ into managed C++). On problem, when using C++ and .Net together.  You cannot safely use pointers to garbage collected memory from C++ (unless you pin garbage collected objects).  pInvoke kind of makes that hard to get right.

Comment: The log shows the pointer to the array getting copied instead of the array content.  One indirection too many, delete `out`.   And use [Out] on the parameter declaration to tell the marshaller to copy back the content.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to pass an array back, the input parameter is already a pointer to a char array with a length of 32, so the declaration is:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate int cb_func_card_reset(nint ptrATR);
```

Then you just need to copy the result to the pointer:

```
private int CardReset(nint ptrATR)
{
    var atrResult = _reader.ActivateICC();
    if(atrResult != null && atrResult.Length <= 32)
        Marshal.Copy(atrResult, 0, ptrATR, atrResult.Length);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but its not) Library developers say, that i should allocate memory and return pointer

Comment: The type of the input parameter is a single pointer, how can you return a pointer to the caller?

Comment: ptrATR has IntPtr.Zero value, or null if we use byte[]

Comment: Then it's wrong, maybe you should ask the developers to test the callback.